# PHP - Incorrect use of static variable?

Tags: php, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to make a simple code in PHP in order to decide when I can make a query.

My code looks like this :

```
$status = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g read 17");
static $status_lpv = 0;

if ($status == 1 )
{   
    if($status_lpv == 0)
    {   
        $status_lpv = 1;
        echo " do the job ";
    }
}

if($status == 0 )
{
    if($status_lpv == 1 )
    {
        $status_lpv = 0;
        echo "do another job ";
    }
}
```

My variable `$status_lpv` is always 0. What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Why do you want to use a static variable? It doesn't seem to be inside a class, Just loose the static and it will work fine.

Comment: What is the value of `$status`?

Comment: @Rolf Thank you for your response. I forgot to say that I'm refreshing the page every 1 second. Do you have any idea how to "store" `$status_lpv` externally ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the code into function (if not there yet) and call the function

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm refreshing the page every 1 second. Do you have any idea how to "store" $status_lpv externally ?

Comment: Depending on how exactly you refresh it. Is there a way to pass it as a parameter? (via GET for example?)

Comment: No, I'm refreshing it using javascript. I think I can "store" the value into a txt file and read it in the if statements. What do you think about that?

Comment: Sure, whatever is working for you. Can be file, can be database, can be in-memory storage. Depends on the other things, for example on load in general, like if each second this happens on many clients at once - then there will also be a concurrency issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store status between http calls in a (static) variable.

You need persistent storage, locking etc. (eg. try a database)